# ClassCastException while injecting dependencies with dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using Dagger2 to inject my dependencies in all of my applications.

Some days ago I started getting Crash Reports for one of the applications from Samsung Android 7.0 (only these) devices.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at de.package.name.MyApplication.get(MyApplication.java:43)
  at de.package.name.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:53)
  at de.package.name.ui.startup.StartupActivity.onCreate(StartupActivity.java:26)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
```

MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupAppComponent();
    }

    private void setupAppComponent() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .userApiModule(new UserApiModule())
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public static MyApplication get(Context context) {
        return (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Relevant part of the BaseActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyApplication.get(this).getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

And finally, the StartupActivity Part:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupComponent(MyApplication.get(this).getAppComponent());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);

    startupPresenter.bindView(this);
}

public void setupComponent(AppComponent appComponent) {
    startupComponent = DaggerStartupComponent.builder()
          .appComponent(appComponent)
          .startupModule(new StartupModule())
          .build();
    startupComponent.inject(this);
}
```

I already updated Dagger to the most recent version (2.11 for now). But I don't have any ideas about this issue. Also, I can't reproduce it on my Samsung S8 7.0 device.

So if you have any ideas, please let me know!

Cheers

**edit:**
If anyone runs into this problem. Take a look here: [RuntimeException with Dagger 2 on Android 7.0 and Samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784685/runtimeexception-with-dagger-2-on-android-7-0-and-samsung-devices/46925736#46925736)
This might be your solution.

Comment: issue is reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Dagger.  The problem is here:

```
return (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
```

The `Context` returned by `getApplicationContext()` is ***not*** guaranteed to be your `Application` instance.  The only situation I've encountered where it wasn't was in an emulator, but it's always possible.

I prefer this approach:

```
private static MyApplication gInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    gInstance = this;
}

public static MyApplication instance() {
    return gInstance;
}
```

This is safe because the `Application` instance is created and its `onCreate` is called before any other Android component is created.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately this changes cause `NullpointerExceptions` accessing the instance. How is this even possible? :/

Comment: @chrjs Did you set your custom application class in the manifest?  Are you calling `instance()` outside of a lifecycle method (e.g., in a field initializer?)

Comment: Yes, its set in the manifest. And is only accessed via `onCreate` of the BaseActivity

Comment: So your code in `BaseActivity` now looks like `MyApplication.instance().getAppComponent().inject(this);`?  Have you tried breaking that down to see which method is returning null?

Comment: Exactly. My problem is, I can't reproduce this issue on my devices. The instance is always set before the get call is called in the Activity.

Comment: @chrjs Issues that can only be reproduced on specific devices are a nightmare. :-/ Did you ever find out anything more about this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm still stuck with weird NullPointerExeptions accessing the instance of the Application. Sorry. :/