# RuntimeException with Dagger 2 on Android 7.0 and Samsung devices

Tags: android, dagger-2, samsung-mobile, android-7.0-nougat

On my Google Play console I see quite a lot crash reports since I started to use Dagger 2, but only on Android 7.0 and mainly on Samsung devices, some Huawai and Motorola devices and some rare Xperia devices:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject (AndroidInjection.java:48)
  at dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.onCreate (DaggerAppCompatActivity.java:43)
  at com.package.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:83)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6956)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

I cannot reproduce the issue since I do not have any affected device at hand, also it seems that not all devices of a type are affected, more like a random startup failure.

From what I learned through research is that most likely the activity's onCreate is called before the activity is actually attached to an application. But I cannot prove this statement...

I am following Google's architecture blueprint for MVP+Dagger.

My Application class:

```
public class App extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        return appComponent;
    }

}
```

My MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Relevant Dagger 2 code:

DaggerAppCompatActivity:
https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/e8d7cd4c29c1316c5bb1cf0737d4f29111fcb1c8/java/dagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity.java#L42-L45

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    AndroidInjection.inject(this); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
}
```

AndroidInjection:
https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/e8d7cd4c29c1316c5bb1cf0737d4f29111fcb1c8/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjection.java#L43-L52

```
public static void inject(Activity activity) { 
    checkNotNull(activity, "activity"); 
    Application application = activity.getApplication(); 
    if (!(application instanceof HasActivityInjector)) { 
        throw new RuntimeException( 
            String.format( 
                "%s does not implement %s", 
                application.getClass().getCanonicalName(), 
                HasActivityInjector.class.getCanonicalName())); 
    }
```

I have no idea how to resolve this crash, but the amount of crashes is too significant to ignore. Since my Dagger 2 usage works perfectly on all other Android versions and devices I assume that it is not caused by the way I use Dagger 2 but somehow by some vendor specific 7.0 implementations. If anybody faced the same issue and found a solution please, please, please help me!

Since this error is driving me nuts I rolled out a test version to 100k users trying to understand where this whole thing goes wrong.

```
public abstract class TestDaggerAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasFragmentInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment> frameworkFragmentInjector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inject();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return supportFragmentInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment> fragmentInjector() {
        return frameworkFragmentInjector;
    }

    private void inject() {
        Application application = getApplication();

        if(application == null) {
            injectWithNullApplication();
            return;
        }

        if (!(application instanceof HasActivityInjector)) {
            injectWithWrongApplication();
            return;
        }

        // Everything seems ok...
        injectNow(application);
    }

    private void injectWithNullApplication() {
        Application application = (Application) getApplicationContext();
        injectNow(application);
    }

    private void injectWithWrongApplication() {
        Application application = (Application) getApplicationContext();
        injectNow(application);
    }

    private void injectNow(Application application) {
        checkNotNull(application, "Application must not be null");

        if (!(application instanceof HasActivityInjector)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s does not implement %s", application.getClass().getCanonicalName(), HasActivityInjector.class.getCanonicalName()));
        }

        AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector = ((HasActivityInjector) application).activityInjector();
        checkNotNull(activityInjector, "%s.activityInjector() returned null", application.getClass().getCanonicalName());

        activityInjector.inject(this);
    }

}
```

The activity is based on Dagger's activity with inlined AndroidInjection code. My thinking was that if this issue would not be resolved by using ApplicationContext instead of `getApplication()` my stack traces should detail whats going on:

- if the issue is caused by `getApplication()` the stack trace would contain `injectWithNullApplication()` or `injectWithWrongApplication()`
- a thrown NPE would show that `getApplicationContext()` returned null
- a thrown RuntimeException would show that the `getApplicationContext()` is not my Application
- if no exception would be thrown either the `getApplication()` or `getApplicationContext()` returned my application and I would not care what actually solved the issue

And here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.package.di.TestDaggerAppCompatActivity.inject (TestDaggerAppCompatActivity.java:49)
  at com.package.di.TestDaggerAppCompatActivity.onCreate (TestDaggerAppCompatActivity.java:31)
  at com.package.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:83)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6942)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2880)
```

So the if clause `!(application instanceof HasActivityInjector)` in `inject()` did not reroute to `injectWithWrongApplication()` but the same if clause caused the RuntimeException in `injectNow(Application application)` on the same Application instance. WTF? I looked like 100 times at my code but if I have an error in there please let me know! Otherwise, I guess there are some really weird things going on in some Vendor implementations of 7.0 which are maybe not fixable...

Based on the discussions on https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/748 I also rolled out a test version that only uses `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getApplication()` in all Dagger components without any difference.

**My application tag from manifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="false">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.package.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.package.GeneratorService" android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Some relevant posts I found for the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840768/android-7-0-and-7-1-getapplication-classcastexception | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752702/android-7-0-classcastexception-in-galaxy-tab-a-10-1 | https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/748 | https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/893

Comment: Same thing happens in our app at the moment. It looks like that our custom `Application` class is not getting called at all (even though it is specified in the manifest), which probably means that default `Application` class is used instead, which in turn means that cast will fail. Still looking for solution though.

Comment: Are you using code obfuscation in your app?

Comment: We do use proguard but Application is added to the rules. It also does not explain why issue happens only sometimes and mainly on Samsung devices.

Comment: Could you give some information about the affected Devices?

Comment: @tynn mainly (over 99% in our case) Samsung devices running Android 7.0. Lots of different models. That is pretty much all they have in common. App has around 2M users, so the numbers should be accurate.

Comment: For my app it is also mainly Samsung, with the top 4 beeing Galaxy A5(2017) (a5y17lte), Galaxy S7 (herolte), Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2ltebmc), Galaxy Note5 (nobleltelgt). Some Huawai devices are also effected, e.g. P9 lite (HWVNS-H), P9 Plus (HWVIE). All devices have Android 7.0 in common, but not all devices of a type are affected, more like a random event.

Comment: I'm not sure I have an answer for you (yet), but I do note that [DaggerApplication#onCreate](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DaggerApplication.java#L78) calls `inject` on your application component after calling `applicationInjector()`, so you probably don't need to do so yourself. Also, do you use multidex, and can you log the dynamic type of `Application` to confirm Dmitry's theory above?

Comment: Jeff, I tried to get the Application&#39;s type but the Play Console does not gather the exepction&#39;s message and Firebase is not yet initialized when the crash occurs.

Comment: Can I see build.gradle or its not there?

Comment: @DenisKnauer before using any of the Dagger's code (i.e. before calling `super.onCreate()`) try to throw an exception with description of the error (like `throw new IllegalStateException("Application is actually: " + getApplicationContext())`). Then it will be logged in Google Play console.

Comment: @Dmitry Zaitsev The error description for a RuntimeException is not logged in the Play console, why would an IllegalStateException be different?

Comment: @DenisKnauer ah, my bad. I did not notice that Google changed that, before it was possible to see the message.

Comment: @DenisKnauer could you please show how your `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest looked like while you still had this bug?

Comment: Sure, see the update 3.

Comment: I'm seeing this crash on Android 9 with a variety of devices

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I found a way to resolve the crashes caused by using Dagger 2 under Android 7.0 for my application. Please note that **this does not resolve the issue with a custom application not being properly used under Android 7.0**. In my case I did not have important logic in my custom Application besides getting Dagger 2 implemented and so I just replaced the `DaggerApplication` based implementation with the `ApplicationlessInjection` below.

**Known issues**

- No dependency injection in custom application classes (probably this isn't a good idea with the freaking Android 7.0 OEM implementations anyway)
- Not all Dagger components where modified by me, I replaced only `DaggerAppCompatActivity`, `DaggerIntentService` and `DaggerFragment`. If you are using other components like `DaggerDialogFragment` or `DaggerBroadcastReceiver` you need to create your own implements but I guess that should not be too hard :)

**Implementation**

Stop using `DaggerApplication`. Either extend your custom application again from the standard `Application` or get rid of the custom application entirely. For the dependency injection with Dagger 2 its not needed anymore. Just extend e.g. `FixedDaggerAppCompatActivity` and you are good to go with the Dagger 2 DI for activities.

You may notice that I am still passing the application context to the `ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance()`. The dependency injection itself does not need the context at all but I want to be able to easily inject the application context into my other components and modules. And there I do not care if the application context is my custom App or some crazy other stuff from Android 7.0 as long as it is a context.

**ApplicationlessInjection**

```
public class ApplicationlessInjection
        implements
            HasActivityInjector,
            HasFragmentInjector,
            HasSupportFragmentInjector,
            HasServiceInjector,
            HasBroadcastReceiverInjector,
            HasContentProviderInjector {

    private static ApplicationlessInjection instance = null;

    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment> fragmentInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<ContentProvider> contentProviderInjector;

    public ApplicationlessInjection(Context applicationContext) {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().context(applicationContext).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment> fragmentInjector() {
        return fragmentInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return supportFragmentInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverInjector() {
        return broadcastReceiverInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector() {
        return serviceInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<ContentProvider> contentProviderInjector() {
        return contentProviderInjector;
    }

    public static ApplicationlessInjection getInstance(Context applicationContext) {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized(ApplicationlessInjection.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ApplicationlessInjection(applicationContext);
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

}
```

**FixedDaggerAppCompatActivity**

```
public abstract class FixedDaggerAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasFragmentInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment> frameworkFragmentInjector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inject();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return supportFragmentInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment> fragmentInjector() {
        return frameworkFragmentInjector;
    }

    private void inject() {
        ApplicationlessInjection injection = ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector = injection.activityInjector();

        if (activityInjector == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("ApplicationlessInjection.activityInjector() returned null");
        }

        activityInjector.inject(this);
    }

}
```

**FixedDaggerFragment**

```
public abstract class FixedDaggerFragment extends Fragment implements HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> childFragmentInjector;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        inject();
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return childFragmentInjector;
    }


    public void inject() {
        HasSupportFragmentInjector hasSupportFragmentInjector = findHasFragmentInjector();

        AndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector = hasSupportFragmentInjector.supportFragmentInjector();

        if (fragmentInjector == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(String.format("%s.supportFragmentInjector() returned null", hasSupportFragmentInjector.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
        }

        fragmentInjector.inject(this);
    }

    private HasSupportFragmentInjector findHasFragmentInjector() {
        Fragment parentFragment = this;

        while ((parentFragment = parentFragment.getParentFragment()) != null) {
            if (parentFragment instanceof HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
                return (HasSupportFragmentInjector) parentFragment;
            }
        }

        Activity activity = getActivity();

        if (activity instanceof HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
            return (HasSupportFragmentInjector) activity;
        }

        ApplicationlessInjection injection = ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
        if (injection != null) {
            return injection;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("No injector was found for %s", getClass().getCanonicalName()));
    }

}
```

**FixedDaggerIntentService**

```
public abstract class FixedDaggerIntentService extends IntentService {

    public FixedDaggerIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        inject();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    private void inject() {
        ApplicationlessInjection injection = ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        AndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector = injection.serviceInjector();

        if (serviceInjector == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("ApplicationlessInjection.serviceInjector() returned null");
        }

        serviceInjector.inject(this);
    }

}
```

**My AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<ApplicationlessInjection> {

    @Override
    void inject(ApplicationlessInjection instance);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        AppComponent.Builder context(Context applicationContext);

        AppComponent build();

    }

}
```

**My AppModule**

```
@Module
public abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    @ApplicationContext
    abstract Context bindContext(Context applicationContext);

}
```

**And for the sake of completeness my @ApplicationContext annotation**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApplicationContext {}
```

---

Hopefully I can help someone else with my code as well. For me I could resolve all crashes related to introducing Dagger 2 and the weird Android 7.0 versions.

If more clarification is needed just let me know!

Comment: Can you please tell how this differs from the normal flow of Dagger injection? What does your approach solves, that default dagger implementation lacks to do?

Comment: @azizbekian this resolves exactly the issue of the my question. There are some Android 7.0 implementations especially from Samsung that seem to randomly ignore custom applications. If you use DaggerApplication from Dagger 2's android package you will face the situation that some of your Android 7.0 users are not able anymore to start your applicaiton because for whatever reason the extended DaggerApplication **is not** used and so breaks the entire DI implementation and so the app.

Comment: In addition to instances of `getApplicationContext()` not returning the correct subclassed ApplicationContext I'm also seeing instances in our production environment of `getApplicationContext()` returning null which per your implementation above throws an exception.  Is there any reason you couldn't replace ApplicationlessInjection injection 
 `ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance(getApplicationContext());`  with `ApplicationlessInjection injection = ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance(someActivityContext);`.  Seems like all your implementation wants is any context and that should suffice.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (since months) but i'm not extending DaggerApplication. My Custom Application just implements `HasActivityInjector`. And I don't extend from `DaggerAppCompatActivity` or `DaggerFragment`, I just use the static methods `Android(Support)Injection.inject`. So I'm not quite sure, how your (well documented) solution applies to me, can you give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: @Travis, sorry for my late reply, the context is not necessary at all, see following gist, not tested by myself but should work: https://gist.github.com/codiert/f12266637c42988b6a1be0f11be1d8f9. Obviously you need to adjust the Fixed* classes to use `ApplicationlessInjection.getInstance();'`

Comment: @chrjs it does not matter if you use DaggerApplication or your own custom application because the application is simply not used / replaced / ignored. The code from my last reply might better fit your case as it does not need any context at all. And you would need to replace the `Android(Support)Injection.inject` call with my code from the `FixedDaggerAppCompatActivity / FixedFragment .inject` method

Comment: @DenisKnauer great work, thank you for posting this!

Comment: I am getting the same issue while using Hilt , any idea how can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in my app and i resolved it by using below code :

```
Application app = activity.getApplication();
if(app == null) {
     app = (Application)activity.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Comment: It's interesting how this is related to the issue. I do not say that it is **not** related, but at least I have no clue how it might be related.

Comment: I tried using the application context instead of getApplication() without any difference on Android 7.0, as posted in my question as well.

Comment: This does not really fix the issue for us, because we also run some code in our custom `Application` which is now just not invoked.